# eclipse - type cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am following the tutorial from the book "Android Programming Tutorials, 3rd Edition".

In lesson number 3 "A Fancier Form" I experience some problems within Eclipse.

The author says to add the following line of code:

> ```
> public String getType(){
> return(type);
>     }
> public void setType(String type) {        
> this.type=type;
> ```

Which results in having the following code:

```
package apt.tutorial;

public class Restaurant { 
    private String name=""; 
    private String address=""; 
    public String getName() { return(name); } 
    public void setName(String name) { this.name=name; } 
    public String getAddress() { return(address); } 
    public void setAddress(String address) { this.address=address; } 
    public String getType(){ return(type); } 
    public void setType(String type) { this.type=type; } 
}
```

eclipse gives me the following errors:
For the first "Type" I get type cannot be resolved to a variable.
For the second "Type" I get type cannot be resolved or is not a field.

I hope someone can explain me which steps to take to fix this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "type" variable to your class.

Example:

```
public class Restaurant {   
    private String name="";     
    private String address="";   
    private String type="";
    ............
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a field type:

```
package apt.tutorial;
```

public class Restaurant { **private String type= "";** private String name=""; private String address=""; public String getName() { return(name); } public void setName(String name) { this.name=name; } public String getAddress() { return(address); } public void setAddress(String address) { this.address=address; } public String getType(){ return(type); } public void setType(String type) { this.type=type; } }

Answer (score 1):

You dont have an attribute named `type` of type `String`, like:

```
public class Restaurant {
    private String type;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute type, used in getType and setType, is not declared. You need to do it in order to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

**-** You have **not declared** `type` as a field in the class scope, thats why u are getting this error

**For eg:**

```
private String type;
```